# How to detect if a float variable has raised up by 10 in Unity C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm making a runner game in Unity3D and I want to detect everytime the distance (float variable) raises up by 10 to raise the speed a little bit, is it possible ???
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Store the old value. Then check if new value minus old value is > 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, found a solution very quickly thanks to @mjwills !!!
Here's the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : SingleTon<GameManager> {

    private float oldDis;

    void Start()
    {
        oldDis = distance;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {

        if (distance - oldDis >= 10)
        {
            Debug.Log("Raised up by 10 and now it's " + distance + " !!!");
            oldDis = distance;
        } 
    }

}
```

Comment: Do u need oldDis and currenrDis?
Don't u need just one?
And then if(true) { oneDis += "whatever speed u want" }